# how to display nested json array in android recyclerview

Tags: android

I am getting json as below.

How to display purchases array in android recyclerview?

Any advice please? number of purchases will be random.
Do I have nested recyclerview or listview?

```
{"data": [
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "foo",
   "purchases": [
     {"id":10,
      "amount": 500
     },
     {"id":15,
      "amount": 400
     }
   ] 
 },
 {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "bar",
   "purchases": [
     {"id":11,
      "amount": 600
     },
     {"id":13,
      "amount": 1000
     },
     {"id":15,
      "amount": 2000
     },
   ] 
 },
 {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "zoo",
   "purchases": [] 
 }
]}
```

[image]

Comment: can't you just loop through your purchase array and append it to a recycler view row file?
it would be better i guess.

Comment: If you need to show the list as shown above, you can use only one TextView and append purchases amount fields with commas or with other seperators.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Include your json data as a resource, so create `data.json` file under `res/raw`

**Step 2**

Create model classes for your data, here you need two, one for the entire list of "data", and the other one for the list of "purchases"

```
public class DataModel {

    private int mId;
    private String mName;
    private List<Purchase> mPurchases;

    public DataModel(int id, String name, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
        mId = id;
        mName = name;
        mPurchases = purchasesList;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        mId = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }


    public List<Purchase> getPurchases() {
        return mPurchases;
    }

}
```

Purchase data mode

```
public class Purchase {

    private int mId;
    private int mAmount;

    public Purchase(int id, int amount) {
        mId = id;
        mAmount = amount;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return mAmount;
    }

}
```

**Step 3**

Read the json data

```
List<DataModel> data = getData(this, R.raw.data);

    private static JSONArray loadJsonArray(Context context, int resource) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(resource);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            return json.getJSONArray("data");

        } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    private static List<DataModel> getData(Context context, int resource) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = loadJsonArray(context, resource);

        if (jsonArray == null)
            return null;
        List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject dataItem = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray purchasesJsonArray = dataItem.getJSONArray("purchases");
                List<Purchase> purchasesList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < purchasesJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject purchaseItem = purchasesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    Purchase purchase = new Purchase(purchaseItem.getInt("id"), purchaseItem.getInt("amount"));
                    purchasesList.add(purchase);
                }

                DataModel dataModel = new DataModel(dataItem.getInt("id"),
                        dataItem.getString("name"), purchasesList);
                data.add(dataModel);

            }
        } catch (JSONException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

**Step 4**

Now create your `RecyclerView` normally and with an adapter that holds a `List<DataModel>`

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<DataModel> mData;

    // Constructor
    RecyclerAdapter(List<DataModel> data) {
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(listItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataModel item = mData.get(position);
        holder.tvName.setText(item.getName());

        List<Purchase> purchases = item.getPurchases();
        StringBuilder amount = new StringBuilder();
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            amount.append("$").append(purchase.getAmount()).append(", ");
        }

        if (amount.length() > 0)
            holder.tvAmount.setText(amount.substring(0, amount.length() - 2));
        else
            holder.tvAmount.setText("no purchases");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName, tvAmount;

        CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View listItem) {
            super(listItem);
            tvName = listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tvAmount = listItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
        }

    }
}
```

**Step 5**

Build your RecyclerView

```
List<DataModel> data = getData(this, R.raw.data);
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(data);

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Wish that could help you out